# Combining data from one of the three tables when the condition

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

[image]

There are 3 tables. Need to attach one of them depending on the maximum value in the "VALUE" field of the calculated layer? I have problems with programming :) but still I tried (it didn't work):

```
case
when   max( @Delete_fields_Contours_OUTPUT,"VALUE")  <=7   then  'F:/Projects/QGIS/Shallow.ods'
when   max( @Delete_fields_Contours_OUTPUT,"VALUE")  >7<25 then  'F:/Projects/QGIS/Medium.ods'
when   max( @Delete_fields_Contours_OUTPUT,"VALUE")  >25   then  'F:/Projects/QGIS/Deep.ods'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the conditional branch tool:

Rename the input layer to renamed.

Then create three branches with the conditions:

`aggregate( layer:='renamed', aggregate:='max', expression:="ELEV_MIN")<1000`

`aggregate( layer:='renamed', aggregate:='max', expression:="ELEV_MIN") BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500`

`aggregate( layer:='renamed', aggregate:='max', expression:="ELEV_MIN")>1500`

Replace `ELEV_MIN` with the name of your column, and the value limits.

[image]

Then set each each branch as a Dependency to each Join attributes by field value and its input table to join.

[image]